# mathematical operations in a text file usinf awk

Tags: awk

I have a text file which looks like this small example:
in this file the first line of each group is ID and belong each `ID`, there are some lines in which the 1st column is `3-letters character` and 2nd one is a number. 2 columns are `tab separated`.

```
ID1
AAA 17
TTA 3
ATA 6
ATC 12
AAG 9
ACA 13
ATG 21
ACC 13
ACG 5
AAT 12
AGA 11
ATT 22
AGC 11
TAA 3
ACT 8
TAC 12
ID2
AAA 10
AAC 7
AAG 4
ACA 3
ACC 1
ATG 6
ACG 1
```

below also I have a list of `3-letter characters`. I want to get a ratio of `TTA` and other `3-letters characters` belong each `ID` which is also present in the below list.

```
ATT
ATC 
ATA
CTT 
AAC 
CTA 
CTG 
TTA 
TTG
GTT
GTC
GTA
GTG
```

the output for this example would look like this:

```
ID1 0.065
ID2 0
```

for the `ID2`, the ration is `0` because there is no `TTA` and for the `ID1` is `0.065` because `3 divided by 46 is equal to 0.065`. for each `ID`, I only took the `3-letters characters` which are common between above list and the rows below each `ID`. and also 2 columns are tab separated.

I am quite new in `awk` programming language. I wrote the following piece of code, but it does not return what I want. would you please help me to fix it?

```
3_letter_list= [ATT, ATC, ATA, CTT, AAC, CTA, CTG, TTA, TTG, GTT, GTC, GTA, GTG]
awk -F  "\t" '{if($1==3_letter_list), (if $1=="TTA" & ratio=$2/$1)}' filename.txt > out.txt


ID3
AAA 2
AAC 8
ATA 1
ATC 20
AAG 26
ACA 6
ATG 11
ACC 16
ACG 7
AAT 2
ATT 4
AGC 18
TAA 1
TAC 8
ACT 3
AGG 1
TTC 20
TCA 1
TCC 8
TTG 6
TCG 4
AGT 5
TAT 3
GAC 18
GTC 12
TTT 6
TGC 7
GAG 31
TCT 1
GCC 19
GTG 21
TGG 6
GCG 8
CAC 12
GAT 6
CTC 12
GGA 2
CAG 22
GGC 25
CTG 52
CCC 15
GCT 3
GGG 6
CCG 4
CAT 4
CTT 2
CGC 18
GGT 4
CCT 3
CGG 13
```

Comment: `3 divided by 46` - where does `46` come from?

Comment: 3 is the count of TTA and 46 is summation of other characters belong ID1 which are also included in the 2nd list. all of the 3-letter characters that are belong the ID1 are not included in the 2nd list. right?

Comment: *3 is the count of TTA* - it has `6` not `3`. `TTA 6`

Comment: @ RomanPerekhrest: it is fixed

Comment: now, `46` is not actual divider. Update your description

Answer (score 0):

**`Awk`** solution:

Assuming that *list of 3-letter character* groups is saved into `groups_list.txt`.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ a[$1]; next }
     /^ID[0-9]/{ 
         if (id) { printf "%s %.4f\n", id, tta/sum; id=tta=sum="" }
         id = $1; next 
     }
     $1 == "TTA"{ tta = $2 }
     $1 in a{ sum += $2 }
     END{ printf "%s %.4f\n", id, tta/sum }' groups_list.txt file.txt
```

The output:

```
ID1 0.0698
ID2 0.0000
```